# Action and reaction - not the same effect

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

If I  press on something, it presses me back with the same force. if I  press a pillow with my fist, l do not feel pain but if I  press a rock with my fist with the same force, I  do feel the pain. why?

Regardless of the fact that my force gets distributed over the pillow surface, I should still get a reaction on my fist that should equal the force I applied.

To be able to compare the two well, please assume that my force on the rock is also over a similar area to the pillow and not concentrated on narrow points that do not cover the whole fist area.

Comment: You should keep in mind that the analysis of this problem should be done when the forces are in equlibrium (Action = Reaction), i.e. neither your hand or pillow are moving anymore. Based on this, I believe the correct answer is the one given by Nicolas.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you feel as pain is mainly the shearing forces in your hand.

With a pillow, you get a pressure spread evenly on your hand so even though the force is high, it is not sheared.

With a rock, the force is localized to a very small contact zone around which the forces (stresses) are strongly sheared. That's bad for your hand (don't experiment too much with this !) and that's what your nerves try to draw your attention to.

Note that even if the overall area of the contact zone is the same, in the case of the rock the contact is in fact limited to a small number of points until either the rock or your hand changes shape.

Comment: My last paragraph was to address this case but, to avoid confusion, let me change the question a little bit. Let us forget about the rock and make it a uniform bar of steel. Also, to avoid sharp points on my fist (like the knuckle), let us say I use my palm. I will still feel more pain when I press on the steel bar.

Comment: Probably not,  if the bar has the same shape as your palm, as @Nathaniel said.

Comment: You will definitely feel more force on your hand as will be evident because of tense muscles.

Answer (score 2):

The mass and hardness of the pillow are much lower than those of your hand, while those of the rock are much higher. Thus the force of the impact mostly deforms the pillow when you punch it, and your hand when you punch the rock.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to say. Since I am talking about action and reaction, we are talking about two separate bodies in either case. when I press the pillow, I am not concerned about what happens to the pillow. My question is about what happens to me. Same for the rock. The answer has to be from the perspective of this action and reaction. I should experience the same force in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put it in terms of force on a pillow but rather look it from this point of view. To *throw* a fist to something, means that you first gave your fist a certain quantity of motion, say $p$. Then you can model the act of throwing a fist as a collision beetween your fist and the object you are fighting with.

For example, suppose that the rock has a fixed position, a skerry maybe, and also assume a skerry of marshmallows. The rock is almost a rigid body, while the marshmallows mountain is not. That means that when you hit the rock, your quantity of motion changes from $p$ to $0$ very rapidly, while when you hit the marshmallows mountain it is changing *gradually* from $p$ to $0$, since the marshmallows will deform and offer a resistance that increases more gradually than in the first case. This, ofcourse, implies that the force exerted from the rock on your fist is much higher than the force exerted by the marshmallows mountain.

From this discussion, it's clear that you don't feel the same force because, actually, you're not applying the same force.

---

Since there seems to be some confusion, I'll try to put it in an other way: let's think about a mass $m$ free falling on a spring of constant $k_1$ and then on a spring of constant $k_2>>k_1$. Let's analyze the forces on the mass $m$ and on the springs $k_1$ and $k_2$.

*At instant of contact*: the deformation of the springs (supposing they were initially at rest) are zero, so there's no force exerted by the spring on $m$ in both cases. The only force on $m$ is, if we neglige friction, $m\mathbf g$. As you know, this force is applied by the earth on $m$, so the reaction will be applied by $m$ on the earth (and not on the spring as you seem to mean in your comments). OK, so at the instant of contact the presence of a spring is irrelevant.

*One istant later*: it's easier if we think of it in a quantized manner, as a computer does when solving numerically a differential equation. So suppose that for a little interval $\text d t$ the situation is the same as above. If $\text d t$ is small enough, then we can say that the vertical displacement of $m$ is:$$\text d x\approx v \text d t,$$
where $v$ is the speed at the instant of contact. What are the forces now?
The mass is still feeling her weight and exerting her reaction **to the Earth**. Plus, both springs are compressed by an amount $\text d x$, so the force felt in both cases is:$$F_1=k_1 \text d x,\qquad F_2=k_2 \text d x$$
and, since $k_1<<k_2$, also $F_1<<F_2$. The forces exerted by the mass on the springs are $F_1$ and $F_2$, and have nothing to do with the weight of $m$: they would be the same if $m$ was $M$ or $\cal M$! What would change, would be the center of oscillations, but this is another thing.

One last thing: you may be arguing that the mass is exerting its weight on the spring because of the analogy with ground exerting our weight on us when we stand still. I want to make you note that in that case, you don't know a priori the force exerted by you on the ground and it's not automatical that it is $mg$. What you do is saying: "I'm not accelerating, so the total force on me is zero". The total force on you is $m\mathbf g+\mathbf R$, so the reaction $R=-m\mathbf g$. As you see, you can't find the reaction of the ground as a reaction to the force exerted by you using third law: it's the other way around.

Comment: Let us take the case of a free fall on a stack of pillows or marshmallows and compare it with the fee free fall on a steel bar. I am applying my weight in both cases throughout as I decelerate to 0 - almost instantaneously on the steel bar and gradually on the pillow. The force applied was the same and it was present from the beginning (point of contact) in both cases. So, at the point of contact I should feel the same force as reaction. Why is the force I feel related to the rate of deceleration?

Comment: "The force applied was the same" this is false. You're not applying only your weight: You're applying your weight plus a contact force that is the reaction to the force applied on you by the constraint. For the same reasons in my post, this is bigger in the second case.

Comment: The force applied by the constraint is a reaction to my force which is my weight. It cannot be the other way around. Drawing a force diagram of the body, I will find that mg - upward force of pillow = ma. For the constraint, it will be mg + (weight of the pillow) = mass of pillow x acceleration of pillow.

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. I will add some body to my answer.

Comment: You have explained it so beautifully that I am your admirer now :-) You precisely understood what I was asking and where I was failing. Hats off to you!! I have a question that I will ask in a separate comment

Comment: What you so clearly indicated was that if a body presses on another body (be it because of a free fall or because of a simple placement on top), the body does not feel the weight of the body that is put on top. That is true only if the body put on top is at rest. So a dense body feels the whole weight and provides an upward force equal to the weight whereas a soft body does not feel the whole weight and depresses as a response to the delta force that it feels until it too gets dense enough and starts feeling the weight of the body that is on top. Would that be correct to say?

Comment: If what I have said is true then the question is - why does a dense body feel the whole weight and a less dense body not feel the whole weight?

Comment: The reason may have to do with pressure - I am not sure. Since the less dense body has sparsely populated molecules, there are not enough molecules to feel the whole weight ???

Comment: I have another question related to this - let us say that the spring was horizontally placed (I want to get gravity out of the picture) and I apply a constant force, assuming I was accelerating already, to compress it. Still, I will be going from some velocity v into the spring and decelerating to 0. Is your contention, based on your logic above, that even in this case, the spring did not experience the full force that was applied until it was completely compressed?  So, a mass that is accelerating because of force applied on it does not experience the full force??

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to help :-) I guess that the only answer to your second question is "it depends"? In general, the contact force is determined by the problem itself (often by the kinematics) and to find its value you must reason as in the example above. Regarding last question, if you say "I apply a constant force on the spring", then ofcourse you are implying that the spring has that force applied on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10881/discussion-between-kazz8-and-pran)

Comment: I am unable to continue the discussion in chat. I noticed your last comment only today. My mistake. I checked your further answers in the chat room. The room was frozen because of inactivity, so I am unable to enter any information there. I suppose this activity will unfreeze the room. My follow up was: If I am moving a box on some surface with a force F, the ground only reacts with $\mu$mg max. Can I clearly state that the ground never feels a force greater than $\mu$mg, i.e. $\mu_s$mg when the box is about to slide and $\mu_k$mg when the box is sliding?

Comment: Yes you can. If the box is still, it means that $|F|\leq |\mu _s mg|$ and, in that case, $R$ (friction force) equals $F$. If the box is moving, the friction force beetween the two doesn't depend at all on the applied horizontal force, but is simply proportional to the weight.

Comment: I am assuming that I can paraphrase and say "The **force that the ground feels** is independent of the Applied force but only dependent on the weight" (since friction is a response to this force that the ground experiences)

Answer (score 0):

> "please assume that my force on the rock is also over a similar area to the pillow and not concentrated on narrow points that do not cover the whole fist area"

Well, ok, but it's pretty hard to achieve that by pushing against a rock. To do so I guess you would need a rock with a perfect smooth inverted image of your fist, as if you pushed your fist into wet plaster of Paris and let it dry. If you push your fist into such a fist-shaped depression, I think you will not feel much pain.

Of course, a real rock isn't shaped like that. It's either a flat, non-inverted-fist-shaped surface, or else it's rough and jagged. Either way, the force gets concentrated into narrow points that do not cover the whole fist area, and that's why the same amount of force causes pain.

Comment: What if I press against a steel bar with my palm as I indicated or the case of a free fall (on a stack of pillows vs. a steel bar)

Comment: I just pressed my palm as hard as I could into a flat surface and I can confirm that it doesn't hurt at all. I'm not really sure what you mean by "the case of a free fall" - can you elaborate?

Comment: In this case, you may not be hurt but you will feel more force on your palm as indicated above because of tense muscles. By free fall, I mean just a normal fall where the only force acting on you is gravity.

Comment: I don't really get your point. Yes, you feel force on your hand, but your question was about why it hurts when you push into a rock. It hurts because the force is concentrated into small areas, that's all. In the case of pushing your palm into a surface the force is concentrated into small*ish* areas due to tense muscles, but not small enough to cause pain. Regarding free fall, I still don't get it. Are you asking whether it will hurt if both you and the rock are falling? If so, yes, I suppose it would, why wouldn't it? You will push yourself away from the rock in this case of course.